# Audio editing through C++/Java

Tags: java, c++, text-to-speech

I wrote text-to-speech engine (from scratch) and it works pretty fine. But sound needs to be a little bit smoother. I can achieve it in audio editing programs (editing output file). But how can I do complex editing through C++/Java? How other text-to-speech engines do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text to speech engines are applying complex filters on the output audio. These filters depend on the language.

I recommend you to find a good book on audio processing. Since the topic is very complex, a good book might shed some light on the problem.